# Django widget override in admin not working

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been trying to change the widget used in the admin but can't seem to get it to work - there is presumably something I'm not doing quite right after looking at the docs. I'm get a models is not defined error but defining models or changing models.ManyToManyField to use the actual Product.ManyToManyField doesn't seem to work either?

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('supplier', 'name', 'last_updated')
    # model = Product
    inlines = [ProductPricesInline,]
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to import `models`?

```
from django.db import models

# ...
formfield_overrides = {
    models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
}
```